# Focus on input to send keys when app-advanced-select is present

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I have a question regarding getting an element. I have this case:

```
<app-advanced-select e2e="test">
  <div>
     <div>
       <input>
     </div>
  </div>
</app-advanced-select>
```

I'm trying to send keys to that input but i always got it can't focus on element.

```
const currentElement = element(by.css('app-advanced-select[e2e=test]')).element(by.css('input'))

await currentElement.sendKeys('my text')
```

How can i do this, considering that between app-advanced-select and input we have 2 x divs? 
Thank you!

p.s: i cant set an e2e tag to the divs or to the input, because in project source code there are no divs or input there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both of them: `let currentElement = element(by.css('input'))` or `let currentElement = element(by.css('app-advanced-select[e2e=test] > div > div > input'))`